# How to make UIWebViews scale to fit inside collectionView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview

I'm loading `UIWebView`'s inside `collectionView` cells.  In the attributes inspector I have checked Scales Pages to Fit as well as content mode to Aspect Fit, however the WebViews in my app never properly scale?

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "bookCell"

class BookResultsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    var receivedURLs = [NSURL]()
    var contentSize = CGSize()


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BookResultsCollectionViewCell

        cell.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: receivedURLs[indexPath.row] as URL))

        cell.webView.delegate = self

        return cell
    }



    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        contentSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
        webView.scrollView.zoom(to: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height), animated: false)

    }
}
```

Resulting CollectionView: 
[image]

Comment: have you tried calling a zoom on the webView's scrollView?

Comment: I haven't, how exactly would I implement that?

Comment: @GarySabo have you found any solutions for the same?

Comment: I can't even remember this issue @Jaydip  but I dont think so, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

give `cell.bounds` to the `cell.webView.frame`

> in your collectionView method `cellForItemAt`,

set below code,

```
cell.webView.frame = cell.bounds
```

Comment: No change when setting the frame to the cell's bounds

Answer (score 0):

The [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate) have a method called webViewDidFinishLoad, at that time, get the size of your content using:

```
let contentSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero).
```

Then zoom to fit the entire content by using the [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview)zoom method like:

```
webView.scrollView.zoom(to: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height), animated: true)
```

set animated to false if you do not want the user to see each webView zooming as it is done loading.

Note: If the ratio - width to height, of the screen your webView loads it not the same as the ratio of your cell, this method will not work.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this but perhaps as you said the ratios are off because it's zoomed in too far it looks

Comment: That code will attempt to fit the entire screen of the webpage you loaded into the webView, however if the ratio is wrong, depending on the contentSize, part of the width or height will be truncated

Comment: If you wish to exclude certain part of the content, play around with the four parameters of the CGRect during the zoom

Comment: Just so I'm clear, I updated my question's code based on your answer is this set up correctly?

Comment: No, UIWebView have been depreciated for [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview). If anyone still wants to use the depreciated UIWebView this is still valid. In fact I believe this works for WKWebView too